# how to do slideToggle function in particular content?

Tags: html, jquery

Can we cause the click event to do the slideToggle function on particular items only not every content that uses same class?

example

```
<table>
<tr class='good'>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td></tr>

<tr class='good'>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td></tr>

</table?

$('table').click(function(){
    $(.good).slideToggle();
});
```

In the code above I just want to do the toggle in second table row only. Since I am using class to toggle it is toggling everything that uses that class and I can't even give them separate ids because we created that table in jQuery on the fly with data coming from callback function in Ajax.

Comment: `$(".good:eq(1)")` would select the second row

Answer (score 0):

The best practice when it comes to jQuery is to use id for any element that you want them to be manipulated.

Assign row an id and jQuery can quickly and grab these nodes for manipulating like slideToggle(); fadeIn(); or such.